# Vuetify - v-tooltip not responsive on breakpoints?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I face a problem, which I can't solve but I'm not sure if this is a bug of vue / vuetify or if the error is on my end.

This is what I try to accomplish:
Show tooltip only on sm screen sizes and lower. Which is response whatever size the screen has at the loading of page.

This code work as expected, when the page will loaded at sm screen size and is responsive as expected (enlarge screen size to md and higher and reduce screensize back to sm). **But it is not showing the tooltip and is being responsive, when the page will be *loaded* at md screensize and higher and reduce the screen size to sm!**

```js
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="auto" align="center">
        <v-tooltip right :disabled="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp">
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <v-icon color="success" v-on="on">mdi-check</v-icon>
          </template>
          <span>sm screen size!</span>
        </v-tooltip>

        <div class="hidden-sm-and-down">md screen size!</div>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>


<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {

      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!
Meffesino

Comment: If you want to solve this in JavaScript I suggest you to look at the `v-resize` directive. If you want to solve this in CSS - then you will need 2 icons (one with tooltip and one without) and each one of them should be visible only on the appropriate screen size (using a responsive CSS class).

Comment: v-resize might be a workaround ... but I think an additional directive (v-resize), which is linked to an additional method, which is constantly firing on resizing should be the way to go.
If there is no other (cleaner) solution, I will use v-resize

Comment: Depends on your definition for `clear` - the CSS approach with media queries will require 2 copies of the `v-icon` but will avoid the constant event firing.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem some time ago ! for some reason `v-on="on"` doesn't always work with `v-icon` ! but works fine if you put your `v-icon` inside another component like `v-card` ! try this :

```
<v-col cols="auto" align="center">
        <v-tooltip right :disabled="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp">
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">

            <v-card flat v-on="on">
              <v-icon color="success">mdi-check</v-icon>
            </v-card>
            
          </template>
          <span>sm screen size</span>
        </v-tooltip>

        <div class="hidden-sm-and-down">md screen size!</div>
      </v-col>
```